# Converting .arc to .tif (raster) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I got this rainfall data from the Australian Bureau of Meteorology, but it comes in this .arc format which I can't open in QGIS.

After a little bit of googling, I found some relevant instructions for converting it to .tif using 'Raster > Conversion > Translate (Convert Format)'. Whilst this does produce a .tif layer, the layer is empty!

Answer (score 5):

Change the extension of the data file from .txt to .asc.

Below is some sample data [downloaded from BOM](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/averages/climatology/gridded-data-info/gridded-climate-data.shtml):

[image]

Can't see it in QGIS:

[image]

Renamed to .asc:

[image]

Now usable in QGIS:

[image]